# MySQL haversine formula return incorrect distance when LEFT JOIN, HAVING and ORDER BY combined

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, left-join, having

I have a query where I would like to receive a data base on user location (Haversibe Formula), but in some cases user have the option to sort the data by either `distance` **only** or **with** `posts.time DESC`.

Currently I get data by `distance` or `distance` with `posts.time DESC`, but when I do a `LEFT JOIN` in my query the results are different and incorrect (**Please see section for Incorrect result**).

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00291/2

**MySQL Query:** This query include `LEFT JOIN`, `HAVING` and `ORDER BY` which how I want the data to be pulled. However this query pull Incorrect distance.

```
SELECT 
    posts.id,  
    posts.title, 
    posts.location,
    posts.time,
    (3959 
        * acos(cos(radians(?)) 
        * cos(radians(posts.latitude)) 
        * cos(radians(posts.longitude) 
        - radians(?)) 
        + sin(radians(?)) 
        * sin(radians(posts.latitude)))
    ) AS distance, 
    SUM(votes.value) AS votes, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN votes.user_id = ? THEN value END) AS uservote
    FROM posts
        LEFT JOIN votes
            on posts.id = votes.post_id
    GROUP BY posts.id
    HAVING distance < ?
    ORDER BY posts.time DESC
    LIMIT 0, 4
```

**Sample data with above query in JSON [20 Mile Radius Example]:** As you can see the second data is incorrect cause the user radius was **20** and the second data `distance` is above the user input.

```
[
    {
        "id": 127,
        "time": "2015-08-27 23:09:59",
        "distance": 0.017432013625718,
        "votes": null,
        "uservote": null
    },
    {   /*INCORRECT DATA, SHOULN'T BE PULLED*/
        "id": 125,
        "time": "2015-08-15 23:44:03",
        "distance": 126.02295676821,
        "votes": null,
        "uservote": null
    },
    {
        "id": 123,
        "time": "2015-08-12 16:23:03",
        "distance": 16.196330779751,
        "votes": "1",
        "uservote": null
    }
]
```

---

## In different Scenario

Now here I will explain what happen if I change some of the query functions where I get a different type of result.

#### Scenario 1

**Remover `LEFT JOIN` and its `SELECT` request.**

Remove these lines from Main Query above:

```
SUM(votes.value) AS votes, 
MAX(CASE WHEN votes.user_id = ? THEN value END) AS uservote
LEFT JOIN votes
        on posts.id = votes.post_id
```

**Result:** As you can see everything here is pulled correctly. but this is not what I want cause I need other data from `votes` table.

```
[
    {
        "id": 127,
        "time": "2015-08-27 23:09:59",
        "distance": 0.017432013625718
    },
    {
        "id": 124,
        "time": "2015-08-12 16:23:30",
        "distance": 16.409455725798
    },
    {
        "id": 123,
        "time": "2015-08-12 16:23:03",
        "distance": 16.196330779751
    }
]
```

---

#### Scenario 2

**Remove `ORDER BY posts.time DESC` only from the query.** but include the `LEFT JOIN` and its `SELECT` option in main query.

**Result:** As you can see the result now would be only be by `distance`, again not complete to what I want to achieve.

```
[
    {
        "id": 114,
        "time": "2015-08-06 19:25:29",
        "distance": 0.017714521452369,
        "votes": null,
        "uservote": null
    },
    {
        "id": 115,
        "time": "2015-08-06 19:25:58",
        "distance": 0.017432013625718,
        "votes": "-1",
        "uservote": null
    },
    {
        "id": 116,
        "time": "2015-08-06 19:26:19",
        "distance": 0.017432013625718,
        "votes": "1",
        "uservote": null
    }
]
```

---

#### Scenario 3

**Using `WHERE` clause**

If I use `WHERE distance < ?` before `GROUPE BY` I get an **error**, which is self-explanatory.

**Error:**

> Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause

Comment: What happens if you use `GROUP BY` in a standard way, rather than trying to exploit the notorious nonstandard MySQL extension to that feature?   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @OllieJones I get the **Scenario 1**

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks, I was able to get it working. I just need to add `posts.time` to `GROUP BY`